# Thymeleaf fitered lists without spring dialect

Tags: thymeleaf

I would like to use the Thymeleaf StandardDialect as opposed to the SpringStandardDialect. Now using the StandardDialect is there a way to apply filters in lists based on a certain condition?

For example I have a array of products with a category and I would like to get a count of the number o products with category = "ABC"

Something like (this example does not work):

```
<div th:text="${#lists.size(products[category='ABC'])}">count</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by not using the spring standard dialect.  This expression does what you want with thymeleaf's default configuration (but it is a SpEL expression):

```
<div th:text="${#lists.size(products.?[category='ABC'])}">count</div>
```